# How to inspect why facebook comment is narrow?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like

[image: When i click Like Button]

This is when i press Like button. How to inspect where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/firebug/).

There is an option in context menu of the page "Inspect element with Firebug" which will allow you to select element on the page and you'll see all its properties and styles, and layout borders.

This way you'll be able to track down which element of the page or css causes a certain layout/size.